# SSL Certificate without Private Key

Tags: ssl-certificate, private-key

I have SSL Certificate with below files and dont have privatekey as CSR generate with this key:

root.crt, server.crt, intermediate.crt

I want to use this certificate on one of my vm of Ubuntu 23.04 apache2 server.

Your step by step guidance is required.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have access to the system where this certificate is still being used? There are ways to extract the private key from the certificate store on Windows and probably also for other OS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't!

If there is a way to use public key, and root certificates to use it everyone will download some public certificate and represent self as someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Romeo Ninov is correct - you **must** have a private key in order to use this certificate. In many cases you actually provide the private key as part of the process of creating the certificate. Once you have found it, ask again.

Comment: You meant, in the process of creating the CSR (certificate signing request), I guess? It is the only step which is performed locally. Then you submit that CSR and the whole process of creating the certificate based on this CSR is performed by the CA, where you **must never** provide your private key.